# Calculating $\int\limits_0^\infty \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) \; dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f_n(x) = ae^{-anx} - be^{-bnx}$ where $0 < a < b$. Find the value of $\int\limits_0^\infty \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) \; dx$.

It's not 0, and I'm not really sure how to do this. I tried splitting the integral into two integrals (one with the $a$ terms and one with the $b$ terms), which isn't something quite justifiable, just to see what would happen, but I got two divergent integrals (using the geometric series). Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind I’m an idiot

Comment: it seems like even by some careful analysis the integral still diverges.

Comment: @Szeto: $$ \left[\log\left(\frac{1-e^{-ax}}{1-e^{-bx}}\right)\right]_{0}^{+\infty}$$ is convergent. Frullani's integral can be invoked.

Comment: @Seh-kai Did you solve this question? I know that the answer is $\ln(\frac{b}{a})$ but I don't know how to get there and I first like to show that this is actually integrable. I posted my question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2893648/lebesgue-integrability-of-sum-n-1-infty-f-nx-where-f-nx-ae-anx-b
Maybe you would like to answer it?