# Lebesgue integrability of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$, where $f_n(x):=ae^{-anx}-be^{-bnx}$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, logarithms, exponential-function, lebesgue-integral

Let $f_n(x):=ae^{-anx}-be^{-bnx}$ where $0<a<b$. Show that  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,\infty)$ and that 
 $\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)=\ln(b/a)$.

Any hints on that? Lebesgue integrable means that $\int|f|<\infty$, but I don't know how to show that here and how to calculate the integral. I was thinking About using the Dominated Convergence Theorem, but couldn't find an estimate.

Comment: Have you considered trying to evaluate the sum explicitly? It's just a difference of geometric series and $x\in[0,\infty)$. Just be careful when $x=0$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2876799/calculating-int-limits-0-infty-sum-limits-n-1-infty-f-nx-dx

Comment: @AlexR. Can you give any hint on that? It seems like considering the two geometric series independently and calculating their integral doesn't work. So how can I evaluate the sum?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks, I saw the post, but unfortunately the question doesn't has an answer… It seems like the Person qho asked the Question figured it out on his own without posting an answer. So do you have any hints? Other then the Frullani integral mentioned in some comment, I have never heard about this...